# Webview is auto clearing the session/cookies of website in React Native Webview

Tags: android, react-native, cookies, session-cookies, react-native-webview

We are using Webview for three websites in react native.

**User-case**

> We have three stores on the homepage. Against every store ,the store
> is opened and user is adding items to cart.     If user comes back and
> go to other store , the previous store session auto clear's out.
>
> We don't want this behaviour of webview. How can we prevent this. ?
> We want to clear the session/cookies like a clear cart on order place
> success.

Is there any workaround guys you can recommend. ?

Looking forward for help

Thank you